# Can I re-use the housing/wiring from a Nutone 669 bathroom exhaust fan (w light) when installing a Nutone 769?

Tags: exhaust-fan

I don't have easy access to the attic to remove the existing housing, but the dimensions are identical and the wiring is already done (two switches - one for fan, one for light).

769 fan specs are here:
http://www.nutone.com/products/product/767f914f-2ee6-4f40-965c-7d859b8583ce

I didn't have luck finding 669 fan specs online but the housing says:
"120V 60Hz 1.6 Amps MAX"

Can I go ahead with the existing housing / power outlets or would it be better to wade through the insulation in the attic and re-wire / use the newer housing?

Comment: do you rewire every time you change a lightbulb or every time you buy a new vacuum cleaner? ..... the fan uses aprox. 200W of power .... the wiring should handle many more times that. ..... that said, you are asking if you need to replace wiring, but you never said anything about the existing wiring ..... so, it is impossible to answer your question

Comment: Not sure why this received - votes it sounds like a good question to me. If tool I can install the new fan and it fits ok go for it, many fans plug in and since it is the same mfg I would have no problem using the original housing.+ for the question.